# How to manipulate pixel data of CSS PaintWorklet context?

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas, css-houdini, css-paint-api

Canvas' context supports `createImageData` and `putImageData`, however, context in paint worklet's `paint` method seems to not support those methods. I know that it doesn't allow reading pixel data from context as it is clearly stated in [this document](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/paintapi):

> A paint worklet’s context is not 100% the same as a  context.
>   As of now, text rendering methods are missing and for security reasons
>   **you cannot read back pixels from the canvas**.

I'm surprised, that it seems like one cannot write pixel to the canvas as well. Am I missing something or what?

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/dkarbayev/pen/JwXwVd?editors=1010) I made to demonstrate the issue - when I run it, Chrome prints `Uncaught TypeError: ctx.createImageData is not a function` in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [current specs on the *PaintRenderingContext2D*](https://drafts.css-houdini.org/css-paint-api/#2d-rendering-context) have this note:

> Note: The [PaintRenderingContext2D](https://drafts.css-houdini.org/css-paint-api/#paintrenderingcontext2d) implements a subset of the [CanvasRenderingContext2D](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#canvasrenderingcontext2d) API. Specifically it doesn’t implement the [CanvasImageData](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#canvasimagedata), [CanvasUserInterface](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#canvasuserinterface), [CanvasText](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#canvastext), or [CanvasTextDrawingStyles](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#canvastextdrawingstyles) APIs.

So it's not only the *getImageData* method that hasn't been implemented, but the whole [CanvasImageData](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#canvasimagedata) one, which includes

- *createImageData*
- *getImageData*
- *putImageData*

---

It's probably worth noting that the ImageData Interface is not even implemented on the [paintWorkletGlobalScope](https://drafts.css-houdini.org/css-paint-api/#paintworkletglobalscope) API, nor is the ImageBitmap one, so we can **not** even do something like

```
const i_data = new ImageData(w, h);
// some pixel manips
createImageBitmap(i_data).then(img => {
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'copy';
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
});
```

even though it would have been a way to do what you wanted, without having the underlying problems induced by *getImageData*...

Comment: bummer! I was experimenting with Paint API and wanted to achieve higher performance pixel manipulation rather than drawing simple primitives.